# JS Timeline - Scroll to specific event on load

Tags: javascript, timeline

I have a timeline that works.  I need it to scroll to a specific event on load, so that the past events are no longer in view. How can I alter my code? Like this timeline: https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/bWwPwM

Here is my js code.

```html
(function() {

  // VARIABLES
  const timeline = document.querySelector(".timeline ol"),
    elH = document.querySelectorAll(".timeline li > div"),
    arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".timeline .arrows .arrow"),
    arrowPrev = document.querySelector(".timeline .arrows .arrow__prev"),
    arrowNext = document.querySelector(".timeline .arrows .arrow__next"),
    firstItem = document.querySelector(".timeline li:first-child"),
    lastItem = document.querySelector(".timeline li:last-child"),
    xScrolling = 280,
    disabledClass = "disabled";

  // START
  window.addEventListener("load", init);

  function init() {
    setEqualHeights(elH);
  }

  // SET EQUAL HEIGHTS
  function setEqualHeights(el) {
    let counter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      const singleHeight = el[i].offsetHeight;

      if (counter < singleHeight) {
        counter = singleHeight;
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      el[i].style.height = `${counter}px`;
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: can you please also provide the html/css of your timeline?

Comment: https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/bWwPwM